Proof that if $I, J \trianglelefteq R$ then $M_n (I) \cdot M_n (J) = M_n (IJ)$
I want to proof the following proposition. If $I, J \trianglelefteq R$ then the product of matrix ideals $M_n (I) \cdot M_n (J) = M_n (IJ)$.
Let's consider the matrices $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_n (I)$ and $B = (b_{ij}) \in M_n (J)$.
Their product is a matrix $C = AB = (c_{ij})$, where $c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$.
Because the $a_{ik} \in I$, and $b_{kj} \in J$, then $c_{ij} \in IJ$. Hence, $M_n (I) \cdot M_n (J) \subseteq M_n (IJ)$.
Let it now $D = (d_{ij}) \in M_n (IJ)$.
Then $d_{ij} = \sum_k a_k b_k$, where $a_k \in I$, $b_k \in J$. How can we deduce from this that $a_k$ and $b_k$ are coefficients of some matrix and that sum looks like a matrix product?

Note that the product of two ideals is defined as the set of finite sums of pairwise element products.
